How to override a specific condition inside filter "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation"
I am using WooCommerce subscription and Mollie Payments for WooCommerce plugin.
It supports multiple subscription product to be purchased on a single checkout process, however when user tries to do a Resubscription it throws below error

A subscription has been removed from your cart. Due to payment gateway restrictions, different subscription products can not be purchased at the same time.

I found a hook "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation" which is used in core WooCommerce for the above validation restriction , how to override this to bypass this validation for the resubscription scenario?
If bypassing the validation is not a better solution how can i resolve this?
I tried the below hook
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'wc_allow_multiple_subscriptions', 15, 5 );

function wc_allow_multiple_subscriptions($passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null)
{
  $removed_message = 'A subscription has been removed from your cart. Due to payment gateway restrictions, different subscription products can not be purchased at the same time.';

  if (!$passed && WC()->session->__isset('removed_subscription') && WC()->session->get('removed_subscription') === $removed_message) {
    $passed = true; // Allow adding multiple subscriptions

  }

  return $passed;
}


This error notice is passed in plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-cart-validator.php  for maybe_empty_cart method near line 64… If you look at the related IF statement conditions (near line 60), at least one available payment gateway needs to support multiple subscriptions (this is ok as you enabled Mollie payments), manual renewals option needs to be disabled and the subscription to be renewed has not to be in cart (which is logic).

I disabled manual renewal option in the woocommerce subscription settings

"Accept manual renewals" option is disabled but still the same issue

When you do a resubscription, is it on an empty cart?

Out of 2 subscription product in a single subscription order , only 1 subscription product is added to checkout page by showing the above warning message.

This looks like a bug, you should report that to the subscription plugin support.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
